# Change image size

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-volley

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);        
RequestQueue mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(mQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
        @Override
        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        }

        @Override
        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            return null;
        }
    });
ImageLoader.ImageListener listener = ImageLoader.getImageListener(img,
            R.drawable.default_image, R.drawable.failed_image);
imageLoader.get(url, listener);
```

I can get an image from the Internet by above code.

And I want to change the size of the image.

Can I change image size by code?

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap newBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, your_radius,your_radius, false);
```

for example

```
Bitmap newBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b,60,60, false);
```

The newBmp is the scaled down bmp